# data not posting in server with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

post methode
I am trying to give post data with postman. Normally without server postman can post data properly. When I add server postman showing loading infinity time. My data is:

```
{
    "name":"Fahim",
    "age":26
}
```

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./modal/user");
require("dotenv/config");
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.DB_CONNECTION_STRING,
  { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true },
  (req, res) => {
    console.log("connected");
  }
);

app.post("/create_user", async (req, res) => {
   try {
    const myuser = new User(req.body);
    await myuser.save();
    res.send(`User created ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);
  } catch {
    (err) => {
      console.log(error);
    };
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("its Listening from 3000port ");
});
```

// Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

const User = new Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", User);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "connected" message is being shown (indicating that Mongoose was able to connect to the database), your `catch` statement inside the POST handler is incorrect and will not show any errors. It will also not end the request, causing the connection to not be closed until a timeout occurs.

A better way of handling errors:

```
app.post("/create_user", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const myuser = new User(req.body);
    await myuser.save();
    res.send(`User created ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).end(error.message || 'an error occurred');
  }
});
```